# Why doesn't this for loop seem to execute although the condition is still true?

Tags: php, for-loop, unset, array-splice, array-unset

In the following SSCCE, why isn't the `for` loop being executed for `$a` greater than 3, although the condition should let it execute till `$a` becomes 5.

And the output of the last statement is even more weird.

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to delete the elements have the `Select one` value for the element/variable `word`, such that the resulting array is:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [word] => alpha [sentence] => A is the first letter in the word Alpha. ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [word] => beta [sentence] => B is the first letter in the word Beta. ) )`

The question is that what is messing it up and what can I do to fix it?

```
<?php 

$objectOne = new stdClass;
$objectOne->word = 'alpha';
$objectOne->sentence = 'A is the first letter in the word Alpha.';

$objectTwo = new stdClass;
$objectTwo->word = 'beta';
$objectTwo->sentence = 'B is the first letter in the word Beta.';

$objectThree = new stdClass;
$objectThree->word = 'Select one';
$objectThree->sentence = '';

$items = array($objectOne, $objectTwo, $objectThree, $objectThree, $objectThree, $objectThree );


print_r($items);//check
echo '<br><br>count($items) >> '.count($items).'<br><br>';//check


for ($a=0; $a < count($items); $a++) {
    echo '<br><br>We are entering index '.$a.'<br><br>';//check
    echo '<br>'.$items[$a]->word.'<br>';//check

    if ( ($items[$a]->word)=="Select one"  ) {
        echo '<br>YES if ( ($items['.$a.']->word)=="Select one"  ) AT '.$a.' INDEX.<br>';//check
        unset($items[$a]);
        /**/array_splice($items, $a, 1);
    }

    echo '<br><br>We are leaving index '.$a.'<br><br>';//check
}


echo '<br><br>AFTER:-<br>';//check
print_r($items);//check

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [word] => alpha [sentence] => A is the first letter in the word Alpha. ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [word] => beta [sentence] => B is the first letter in the word Beta. ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [word] => Select one [sentence] => ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [word] => Select one [sentence] => ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [word] => Select one [sentence] => ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [word] => Select one [sentence] => ) )

count($items) >> 6



We are entering index 0


alpha


We are leaving index 0



We are entering index 1


beta


We are leaving index 1



We are entering index 2


Select one

YES if ( ($items[2]->word)=="Select one" ) AT 2 INDEX.


We are leaving index 2



We are entering index 3


Select one

YES if ( ($items[3]->word)=="Select one" ) AT 3 INDEX.


We are leaving index 3



AFTER:-
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [word] => alpha [sentence] => A is the first letter in the word Alpha. ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [word] => beta [sentence] => B is the first letter in the word Beta. ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [word] => Select one [sentence] => ) )
```

Comment: Have you having problem in this line `echo '<br>YES if ( ($items['.$a.']->word)=="Select one"  ) AT '.$a.' INDEX.<br>';//check
`

Comment: @Saty Yep. It is only printed till the value of `$a` becomes 3. I am editing the question to post complete output of the example.

Comment: Try `unset($items[$a]->word);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is not always true. The condition in your for loop recalculates the size of the array in each iteration. The length of the array changes whenever an item is removed.

The value of `$a` and `count($items)` each time the condition is checked is as follows:

```
$a | count($items) | $a < count($items)
---------------------------------------
 0 | 6             | true 
 1 | 6             | true
 2 | 6             | true
 3 | 5             | true  -- $items[2] was removed
 4 | 4             | false -- $items[3] was removed
```

You should store the size of the array in a variable and use that instead. Also since `array_splice` doesn't preserve numeric keys you will eventually get an undefined offset notice when trying to access `$items[4]` and `$items[5]`. That line is not required.

```
$count = count($items);
for ($a=0; $a < $count; $a++) {
```

Better yet you can use a `foreach` instead of the `for` and use `$item` instead of `$items[$a]`:

```
foreach ($items as $a=>$item) {
    echo '<br><br>We are entering index '.$a.'<br><br>';//check
    echo '<br>'.$item->word.'<br>';//check
    ...
    unset($items[$a]); //can't use $item because it is a copy and not a reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `temp` variable for iteration as you unset the key of main during the for execution. Maybe, this should work :-

```
$temp = $items;
for ($a=0; $a < count($temp); $a++) {
  echo '<br><br>We are entering index '.$a.'<br><br>';//check
  echo '<br>'.$items[$a]->word.'<br>';//check

  if ( ($items[$a]->word)=="Select one"  ) {
      echo '<br>YES if ( ($items['.$a.']->word)=="Select one"  ) AT '.$a.' INDEX.<br>';//check
      unset($items[$a]);
      /**/array_splice($items, $a, 1);
  }

  echo '<br><br>We are leaving index '.$a.'<br><br>';//check
}
```

Comment: This will throw an error since array_splice doesn't preserve numeric keys.